# some of the conditions using nested if statements in java not met

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class GateWay{

public static void main(String [] args){
boolean male = true;
boolean female = false;

Scanner inputGender = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Are you male, true/ false: ");
String gender = inputGender.next();

if(true){
System.out.println("Type your age Sir...");

}else if(false){
System.out.println("Type your age Maam...");}

Scanner inputAge = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
int age = inputAge.nextInt();


if(male == false){ 
if( age < 18 ){
System.out.println("you are too young a girl, go home");

}else if( age > 40 ){
System.out.println("you are too old , go home your body is now weak");

} else if((age > 18 ) && (age <= 40 )){System.out.println("Enter and Enjoy Maam");
}
}

if (male == true){
if( age < 22 ){
System.out.println("you are too young a boy, go home");

}else if( age > 80 ){
System.out.println("you are too old , go home your body can no longer take alcohol");

} else if((age > 22 ) && (age <= 80 )){System.out.println("Enter and Enjoy Sir");
}
}
}
```

}

//i have this code which filters traffic at a bar.now the problem is all the conditions for females are not being met.The code is only executing male conditions.How do I go about it to rectify this

Comment: `if(true)` is useless, `if(false)` won't be executed, ever.

Comment: `else if (false)` is (if possible) even more useless.

Comment: You never actually set the value of `male` or `female` based on user input, so `male` is always **true**.

Comment: You really need to sit down with some paper and pencil to work this out. Not only will `else if(false)` never hit, but `if(male == false){ ` will never hit either as you never change the value of the variable `male`. You bring in `gender` as a string and do nothing with it. Sit with paper and pencil and write out your variables and their values as you come to them in the code. Trace through the logic to see where it would go/not go.

Comment: You should also add some validation to make certain that you are getting the string "true" or "false" from the user, but that is only after you work out your logic issues here.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
  You will always enter this statement.
  A good IDE should indicate this as suspect
 */
if(true){
```

You probably want to test the input value :

```
if(gender.equals("true")){
```

Answer (score 0):

//if true doesnt mean anything here i mean compiler could not understand what to do here give some condition there

```
if(gender.equals(true)){
System.out.println("Type your age Sir...");

}else{   // if u have only two conditions then no need to give else if just else is sufficient
System.out.println("Type your age Maam...");}
```